# Extension of existing License agreement to a new Party

Tags: contract-law, licensing, software

Two Parties have signed a software license agreement.
Now one the affiliates of the Licensee wishes to extend the scope of such license in order to cover new software. But they want to sign this "amendment" to the original agreement themselves.

Is it possible to do that even when the Affiliate obliges himself to comply with the terms of the Agreement signed by its parent company?
The reason i write "amendment" is because i'm not sure if such a construct only configurates an amendment per se or rather a different kind of agreement (adoption?).

What should be the proper way to proceed here?

Comment: Generally, if you try to revise or update a contract, all parties need to sign and be aware of the changes.

Comment: Well, that is why I wrote "amendment" (with quotation marks). There's no actual change made to the existing agreement. The new party (which is an Affiliate of the original party) will be just saying that it adopts the same T&Cs of the existing license.

Comment: But maybe the other party doesn't want to offer the Affiliate the same T&Cs.  They are in no way obligated to (unless there are suitable terms in the contract of course).

Comment: The question is not really if the other party wants to offer the same terms to the affiliate or not. The licensor and the affiliate's licensee have already agreed on that. My question is what is the proper legal document to do that? An adoption/accession agreemeent?